# Importing dirty CSV into MYSQL without preprocessing

Tags: mysql, csv

I have CSV data in the following format:
username:password
The password column is unescaped meaning it may contain a further :
The objective is to import 80+GB as quickly as possible into MYSQL for further analysis

I am wondering if it would be possible to define a `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement which would accommodate a row like username:pass:word

I am also unsure between MyISAM and CSV as storage engine - leaning towards CSV at this stage although MyISAM indexes might be useful.

I've tried InnoDB as storage engine which was a bad idea.
I've tried pre-processing the CSV with awk to replace the first : by \t then LOAD DATA INFILE with \t separator

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/data/1.txt' 
INTO TABLE data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' ;
```

Ideally, I'd like to import a CSV file from MYSQL with a single statement that performs the processing and importing.

Fallback would be simply ignoring any errors generated by LOAD DATA INFILE.. which is actually quite acceptable considering on average 10 errors out of 10000 rows

Comment: 'I've tried InnoDB as storage engine which was a bad idea' - really ,why? It's what I would have gone for - can you add a few lines of your csv file as text please.

Comment: Innodb seems to focus more on consistency and transactions whereas what I want is fast insert and very fast full table lookup - CSV line1=user1:passw0rd line2=user2@gmail.com:pass:w@rd line3=otheruse:123446

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491823/when-to-use-csv-storage-engine-for-mysqlis worth a read - I doubt that csv would be quicker than innodb when fetching given its lack of indexing but nothing to stop you benchmarking,